# Avoid blocking from bluetooth callbacks

Tags: bluetooth, sd-card

I'm developing a wearable data logging device. Sensors are sampled at 20Hz, and written to a SD card through a buffer. There is an Android app that could query the status of data collection (size of written files, latest timestamp etc) through bluetooth LE.

```
// timer interrupt 20Hz
// reading sensors to buffer
ISR() {
    int a = analogRead(A0);
    buffer.push(a);
}

void loop(){
    if buffer.isFull() {
        myFile.open("data.csv", FILE_WRITE);
        myfile.print(buffer.getData());
        myFile.close();
    }
}

// possibility of blocking data collection process
RFduinoBLE_onConnect() {
    int freeSpace = SD.vwd()->fileSize();
    // other operations for monitoring data collection process
    RFduinoBLE.sendInt(freeSpace);
}
```

I am worried that long operations inside RFduino callback function might block the data collection process. (freeSpace is an example, I am planning for other useful data for monitoring process). Also, one could repeatedly try to connect to get updated status data.

What is the recommended technique to make sure that data collection process will not be affected?

UPDATE:

The actual usage is that RFduinoBLE_onConnect will be called every hour or on demand only. On the other hand, I am trying to deal with worst case of someone trying to call onConnect repeatedly. Is there any way to see that if data collection is busy then reject the RFduinoBLE_onConnect requests?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one easy, but effective improvement is to use 2 buffers for writing data - while you are writing the one full to file, your interrupt can safely push values to the other and then after the other is full, your ISR would go to first one, while the second will be written. So even long open/seek/write/close loop does not get hit by new data arrival.

Then the main problem - RF - I would bet, that the on_connect() is called from interrupt too, as it is not mentioned anywhere in the loop(). In that case you would like to have it as small and fast as possible. So if you are only providing data, I would collect all the data in the main loop() in some variable (structure, class, what you need), get it thread safe as much as possible (atomic operations, or have two instancies, one actually enabled for the callback, the other opened for filling new data, then pointers to point which is which and just reassigning those pointers in atomic way (means disable interrupts, swich two pointers, enable interrupts - interrupts can wait for time need to two pointers be changed - on other hand you have no chance do anything in main loop (as disabling interrupts), while interrupt is actually running)

So (I know, it is just example, but) you know, that fileSize() is changed only after file is written - so save its value to some (volatile, of course) variable each time you write to the file and use that variable in onConnect.

So more like this (did not tested it, just idea):

```
volatile buffs[2];
volatile actBuff;
// timer interrupt 20Hz
// reading sensors to buffer
ISR() {
    int a = analogRead(A0);
    buffs[actBuff].push(a);
}

volatile int freeSpace;
void loop(){
    if buffs[actBuff].isFull() {
        int fullBuff=actBuff;
        cli();             // disable global interrupts
        actBuff = 1 - actBuff; // switch actual Buffer between 0 and 1
        sei();// enable global interrupts 
        // ISR have nice free buffer to fill, we will write and empty the old one
        myFile.open("data.csv", FILE_WRITE);
        myfile.print(buffs[fullBuff].getData());
        myFile.close();
        buffs[fullBuff].empty()
        int tempval = SD.vwd()->fileSize();
        cli();             // disable global interrupts
        freeSpace = tempval;
        sei();// enable global interrupts:
    }
}

// possibility of blocking data collection process
RFduinoBLE_onConnect() {
    // int freeSpace = SD.vwd()->fileSize();
    // do the same trick here // other operations for monitoring data collection process
    RFduinoBLE.sendInt(freeSpace); // use the value from loop
}
```